# Convert C# project to .exe (visual studio 2010)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, project, exe, creation

Is it possible to convert visual studio 2010 express project to .exe file? Yes I know that in Projects -> [FileName of the .sln file] -> Bin -> Debug is .exe file. But when I copy it to other directory/ hdd/ usb it do not work. My project includes .mp3 and .wav files.

Comment: What does "it do not work" mean?

Comment: I bet it throws an exception because it can't find one of your files

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: I got this error message http://imageshack.us/f/34/imc.png/

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just copy the exe. You need to copy all of the dependencies also. If you want to know which explicitly, you could run [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) to see what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Use a compiler... like Inno Script Studio (https://www.kymoto.org/products/inno-script-studio).  It's free and I've been using it for years.  I'm not sure what the express version of Visual Studio has available, but I know the Visual Studio 2012 Professional version has InstallShield LE available which is very easy to use as well.